# Using Google Maps Engine in a custom iOS App

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to leverage Google Maps Engine as a data store for an iOS app that uses the Google Maps SDK. Has anyone ever done that before? I'm having trouble finding examples or reference material on the internet. I can get data layers to show up in a web page using HTML and JavaScript, and I can see data layers in the native Google Earth App, but I want to show this data in my own custom map app.

Here is a link to Google Maps Engine for reference: http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/products/mapsengine.html

Comment: Did you find any example ? I'm trying to do the same thing as you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you will need to get in touch with Google to receive a Maps API. I don't think they just let anyone on the street have it.

http://support.google.com/enterprisehelp/bin/request.py?contact_type=maps_engine&hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the link. I went ahead and filled out the form, but I'm still confused by what they mean by Maps API. I have access to the Maps Engine API, but I am unable to extract any polygon data from it, like the actual points in the shape objects.